# Best equivalent VisualStudio IDE for Mac to program .NET/C#

Tags: c#, .net, macos, ide

I'm using my Mac most time at work. At home there's my Windows computer, where I program with Visual Studio my .NET/C# stuff.

**Because I want to program outside, it would be great to have an equivalent IDE for my Mac.**

**Which software are the best solution in my case to have a similar workplace with the same functionality?**

I prefer open source, but commercial software is okay too.

Comment: New from Microsoft, IDE for Mac, Linux and Windows: https://code.visualstudio.com/Download

Comment: Visual Studio Code requires Mono 3.10 or greater.

Comment: Its worth tracking  [Project Rider](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2016/01/13/project-rider-a-csharp-ide/) from Jetbrains

Answer (score 50, accepted):

MonoDevelop from: http://monodevelop.com/

There is no equivalent to Visual Studio. However, for writing C# on Mac or Linux, you can't get better than MonoDevelop.

The Mac build is pre beta. [From the MonoDevelop site on Mac](http://monodevelop.com/Download/Mac_Preview):

> The Mac OS X port of MonoDevelop is under active development and has not seen a stable release yet. Recent work described by Michael Hutchinson has focussed on improving the usability and stability of Monodevelop on the Mac. This work will be released in MonoDevelop 2.2. Right now it's not finished, and is very much an alpha.

Comment: Hm.. till now I haven't heard much good things about Mono running at Linux-OS'. Is there a difference in the behavior to Linux?

Comment: Don't believe everything you hear. Mono & MonoDevelop are under active development with commercial sponsorship. The improvements with each release of late have been tremendous. Give it a whirl. I think you will be pleasantly surprised.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a try - thanks.

Three questions:
a) Do I need additional software for compiling etc.?
b) Is a tool included to run the compiled software?
c) Is a debugger included?

Comment: xamarin studio you advert costs 300$/year and it is the lowest its price

Comment: Not going to mention what IDE I use / prefer, but coming from that IDE, I fully hate monoDevelop.  It is clunky, unpredictable, and erratic, even 8 years after this post.

Comment: Problem, you can't download precompiled binaries: "MonoDevelop for macOS is available from source

Please refer to the building guide for more information about how to install and configure your MonoDevelop."

Comment: At the time I'm writing this, nothing seems to come close to Rider by Jetbrains. In fact, I even prefer it over VS now, so whether I'm using Linux, Mac or Windows (and I do use all three), I can use the same IDE. But you do have to pay for it.

Answer (score 21):

The question is quite old so I feel like I need to give a more up to date response to this question.

Based on MonoDevelop, the best IDE for building C# applications on the Mac, for pretty much any platform is http://xamarin.com/

Comment: Anyone else willing to vouch for Xamarin? Heard good things about it. But as an IDE, is it better than vanilla MonoDevelop? How about pricing/value aspect?

Comment: I still use Xamarin to develop Apps but Xamarin Studio is the worst IDE I ever used. It has tons of bugs and crashes.

Answer (score 18):

Whilst more of a workaround, if you're running an Intel Mac, you could go the virtualisation route - at least then you can run the same tools.

Comment: +1 to [@middaparka](http://stackoverflow.com/users/109825/middaparka). Specifically, I would suggest Virtual Box with Windows and Visual Studio. At least that's what I do.

Comment: This is basically the route I take, 15 inch 2.33ghz Macbook Pro running VMWare Fusion or under bootcamp if I don't need to bounce between OS's

Comment: Yeah, but thats as clear as whatever. Thanks anyway for this hint.

Answer (score 7):

Coming from someone who has tried a number of "C# IDEs" on the Mac, your best bet is to install a virtual desktop with Windows and Visual Studio. It really is the best development IDE out there for .NET, nothing even comes close.

On a related note: I hate XCode.

---

**Update:** Use Xamarin Studio. It's solid.

Comment: XCode is terrible.  I've been learning Objective C, and that IDE makes an already frustrating language worse.

Comment: Try JetBrains AppCode, it's brilliant!

Comment: @RankoR +1. Actually it's pretty sad that Apple's own IDE is so terrible. ;_;

Comment: This is interesting, I actually love the simplicity of Xcode and Objective C. And as you expect me say, I dislike VB.Net syntax and Visual Studio. C# on the other hand is marvellous. Each to his own

Answer (score -7):

codeblocks.It seems to be good

http://www.codeblocks.org/

Comment: Have you used codeblocks? You can do .net in it from what I can see.