# Best F# IDE for a Mac

Tags: macos, ide, f#

I'm trying to convince a friend of mine to switch from OCaml to F#, however they are programming on a Mac. What is the best F# development experience on top of OS X?

From looking at a [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277430/best-equivalent-visualstudio-ide-for-mac-to-program-net-c), it appears that the [F# Addin for MonoDevelop](http://artwild.blogspot.com/2008/08/f-addin-for-monodevelop.html) is my best bet. Are there any better alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Emacs and tuareg mode:**

http://www.palladiumconsulting.com/blog/sebastian/2007/04/f-mono-and-mac-os-x-warmups.html

Answer (score 2):

The answer is now slightly out of date. There now is a proper "F# Mode" for Emacs, see:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/fsharp-mode/