# Run VS-project on OSX

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I want to join as a team member doing web design work in an ASP.NET/C# project.

The project is setup in Windows environment using TFS for source control.

However, I work on OSX and would love to be able to work in the project without having to setup a developing environment using Parallels or so.

Visual Studio Code seemed promising and I installed a TFS plug-in, but I have no idea how to connect to the project and run it on a http://localhost.

Is there a good way to do this?

(I am more of a designer than a tech person so please bear with me and my stupid questions :))

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Code is certainly one way to view code in C#, but you can't really run it unless you're in [.NET Core](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/dotnet). I think you may be able to [debug with Mono](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_mono-debugging), so that might be worth a look first to see if your application is supported through that route. I've heard that Visual Studio will be available cross-platform sometime in the future (which will be amazing), but for now, the IDE is only available for Windows.

You can try using MonoDevelop which looks like a C# IDE for Mac (http://www.monodevelop.com/) and there's also Xamarin Studio (https://www.xamarin.com/studio). See this [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277430/best-equivalent-visualstudio-ide-for-mac-to-program-net-c).

As for TFS, if you're using Git, you can easily connect to TFS using the server as a remote for your local repo (or clone the TFS instance onto your local machine), or you can use the [command-line for Team Explorer Everywhere](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/team-explorer-everywhere-vs.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for an informative answer. I ended up running it under Windows in Parallels instead for this project to avoid conflicts with my co-workers who are in Windows environment.